# sqlsrv_query vs mssql_query text limit 65536

Tags: php, sql-server

I came to an issue when migrating an application from Linux to Win.
On mssql_query a sql string larger then 65536 is executed.
On sqlsrv_query a sql string larger then 65536 is truncated to 65536 characters.
I've tried to add TEXTLIMIT when calling sqlver_query, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
$sql= "SET TEXTSIZE " . strlen($sql) . ";" . $sql;
```

I appreciate if anybody can point me to the right direction. If text limit on sqlsrv_query can be overruled, or if I should make changes on my application.

tks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx MSSQL's Bulk Import and export posibilities

Comment: how is this topic helping me?

Comment: I had the assumption you needed to migrate the data from Linux to windows.

Comment: Not exactly, what I need is to understand if there is a workaround on 65536 text limit that truncates sql string on sqlsrv_query function